# Visual C fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Tags: c++

Don't know whats wrong, all help will be greatly appreciated.
I'm thinking I am having a problem with a file source, but am not sure.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Assignment 08 ADL, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 3/18/2013 8:37:38 PM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\Assignment 08 ADL.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  Assignment 08 ADL.cpp
1>  Generating Code...
1>  Skipping... (no relevant changes detected)
1>  student.cpp
1>ManifestResourceCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>Assignment 08 ADL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "long __cdecl    decimals(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,int)" (? decimals@@YAJAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@H@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl display(class student)" (?display@@YAXVstudent@@@Z)
1>J:\CO 127\Assignment 08 ADL\Debug\Assignment 08 ADL.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:24.82
```

Comment: The problem was with my #include "COMPFUN.H" i had it in all lower case and for some reason switching it to upper case fixed it.

Comment: The "COMPFUN.H" file is what includes my decimal function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to look at the line above `LNK1120`, the `LNK2019` error tells you what is wrong.

Inside of your `void display(class student)` function you are calling a function named `decimals` that is not defined anywhere in your source code or in a library.

Answer (score 1):

This problem appeared to me when I added .c file instead of .cpp
so check the name of the files as well

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the external variable able to access in your current file.
**For Testing** 
easy way is declare same name local variable for testing your logic working not , later change try to access external variable.

Answer (score 0):

LNK 2019 error is a linker error which generally means some object is not available to the linker. Try clean rebuilding the project and then try to execute it.